# How to calculate spherical harmonic coefficients for indirect diffuse?

Tags: opengl, directx, lighting, graphics-programming, spherical-harmonics

After reading the article "An Efficient Representation for Irradiance Environment Maps", I'm a bit confused as how to calculate the spherical harmonic coefficients.  I'd like to generate these coefficients given a cube map that I've generate dynamically in engine.

I'm currently using DirectX 11, but I have some familiarity with OpenGl. Some tips on calculating these coefficients would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This help at all? https://dickyjim.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/spherical-harmonics-for-beginners/

Comment: That post has been helpful in helping me find more information on spherical harmonics(SH), but it doesn't go into detail about calculating the SH from a cube map.  I've read some of the other articles he mentions, but honestly much of the math has gone over my head.  From what I can tell, the way to calculate the SH is by iterating of the entire cubemap and applying the formula found in "An Efficient Representation for Irradiance Environment Maps" for each pixel.  I think this is done by deriving the normal vector from the position of the pixel. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Not sure myself. I think it also has to do with using Lagrange polynomials as basis functions, similar to how bezier curves work with Bernstein polynomials. I also saw some stuff with bandlimiting and windowing, similar to what you see with DSP audio stuff and fft. Wish I knew how it worked better as well :p

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you solved the problem, but since I am working with SH I can tell you that the best way to project a cubemap so far is that of Peter Pyke Sloan. Here [his paper on SH](http://www.ppsloan.org/publications/StupidSH36.pdf), he basically sums each contribute from each pixel weighted by some value obtained from its uv (st in opengl) coordinates. And then all coefficients are normalized by a value obtained by the sum of all pixels weights.